# Django, update page with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I study Django and want to use ajax. Read some examples, but have problem.
I need to show all posts by click on link with name site.
view:

```
def archive(request, page_number=1):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    current_page = Paginator(posts, 3)
    if request.is_ajax():
        t = loader.get_template("archive_ajax.html")        
    else:
        t = loader.get_template("archive.html")
    c = Context({'posts': current_page.page(page_number),
                 'username': auth.get_user(request).username})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

base.html:

```
<h1><a class="refresh" >mysite.example.com</a></h1> (I need click it and update posts )

<div class="content">
<div>
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
</div>
</div>
```

archive.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% for post in posts %}

{% include "archive_ajax.html" %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

archive_ajax.html (problem not here, I mean firstly I need to solve problem which higher   ):

```
<h2><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">  {{ post.title }} </a> </h2>
<p> author: {{ post.author.username }}</p>
<p> {{ post.timestamp | date:"l, F jS, Y" }} </p>
<p> {{ post.body }} </p>
```

In base.html includ jquery: `<script src="/static/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>`

And I try to write  code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".refresh").click(function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $(".content").load("/blog/");                
 });
});
```

when I click on link I see it on the place where might be posts:

```
 {"content": "

\n
\u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440:

\n
\n
\n", "status": 200, "statusText": "OK"}
```

In command line I see `"GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 151`

I try another way and write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".refresh").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/blog/", 
        success : function(newdata) {
             $('.content').html(newdata);
         }
  });
});
});
```

And now I can see nothing in place where might be posts.
In command line I see "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 151`

In view I add print

```
if request.is_ajax():
    t = loader.get_template("archive_ajax.html")
    print('it is query'`)
```

and in command line I see message - it's query, for ajax and js.

I use python 2.7.3, Django 1.6.5 and jquery 1.11.1.min.

Thank you all! I find my mistake, it was in ajax and in template archive_ajax.html. It's my inattention I think. In template I forgot to add loop for {{posts}}. now it's:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<h2><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">  {{ post.title }} </a> </h2>
<p>автор: {{ post.author.username }}</p>
<p> {{ post.timestamp | date:"l, F jS, Y" }} </p>
<p> {{ post.body }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

And in ajax I correct it:

```
$('.content').html(newdata.content);
```

Comment: You have a TemplateDoesNotExist error (for arhive_ajax.html), check your templates.

Comment: Oh, I  was not paying attention. the mistake was in view                t = loader.get_template("arhive_ajax.html")        
 , I corrected it, now t = loader.get_template("archive_ajax.html")  Now when I click to link I see in the place where might be posts: {"content": "

\n
\u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440:

\n
\n
\n", "status": 200, "statusText": "OK"}

Comment: First of all you are using POST, why would you post? if you only need to fetch use GET (in your ajax).

Comment: I try with GET in ajax. still nothing in place where might be posts.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to write:

```
<h2><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">  {{ post.title }} </a> </h2>
```

Take a look at the `{% url %}` [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

**Edit** - Disclaimer: the current user has not enough rate to comment. That's why this apparently answer-less answer is posted here.

Comment: Why is this not a good practice? This seems perfectly reasonable to me. The OP is using this as a URL parameter most likely, anyway...

Comment: Because Django has special tag for this case and url "name" param.

Comment: He is not grabbing a pre-defined URL; he is passing a parameter to aURL. Sure, he could use something like `<a href='{% url "blog" %}/{{post.id}}'>...</a>` but that does *not* solve his original problem. If you think it does, please explain why in your answer. :) As it stands, your answer should be a comment. : )

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was talking about. That was just my tip.

Comment: *Most* of the time, a tip should be a comment. : ) Just for future reference.

Comment: I don't have enough rate for comment. Sorry.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha -- my apologies. Didn't realize. Feel free to put a disclaimer in your answer so people don't down-vote it to oblivion as being "irrelevant." Happy SO-ing!

Comment: thanks you, it will help me in the future. But it's not solve problem. Maybe I write not correct ajax?

Comment: Do you get your 'posts' in template context?(you can check it in debugger)